# Translate old German postcard to English

Tags: german-language, translation

[image: Scan of postcard in German]

I have found an old postcard that was sent to my Nana & Grandad. I came across it along with a few German books and other documents when clearing their house.

I've tried to figure it out using Google Translate, but some of the words are hard to understand due to the hand writing.

Would it be possible for someone to translate it for me?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to. Before starting to translate your document, how far have you got with simply trying to transcribe it? I think asking the community to both transcribe and translate a whole document makes your question insufficiently focused. I think you should focus any similar questions on where you are stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I've not used this site before & I've just finished the tour. I had found a previous post that had something similar with a translation so that's why I made my post. I have tried to transcribe, but I have no clue when it comes to German writing & the handwriting is making it difficult. I have found a whole book of my Grandads family tree which is easier to transcribe as it's typed. Which is so cool to see :)

Comment: Perhaps mark the words you're finding hard to understand, so we can focus on those.

Comment: This “old postcard” is about entering stores with masks and a virus going around.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  While the community is usually happy to help with transcribing (and even translating) a small part of a document where you are stuck to ask it to transcribe (and translate) a whole document equates to asking multiple questions and is too broad for focused Q&A.

Comment: Pointless now but am I the only one that wants to run this through photoshop and do a perspective crop on the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

German:

> Liebe Rose + Friedhelm, danke für die Post aus England; ja der Virus wird weiterhin unser aller Leben bestimmen... Viel zuhause bleiben, mit dem großen Garten haben wir ja Glück. Können immer raus, auch wenn es viel Arbeit ist. Urlaube gestrichen, alle bleiben in Deutschland, bis jetzt viele im Schwarzwald. Bei Volker infiziert, aber alle wieder genesen, niemand verstorben. Wir gehen nur mit Maske in Geschäfte, Bus + Bahn, aber da muß man durch, wir lesen viele Bücher, schauern fern + spielen Karten. Wir schicken diese Karte, damit Du den alten Monnemer Wasserturm auch in Middlesbrough sehen kannst. Ein paar Kleinigkeiten schicken wir los, so habt Ihr auch eine kleine Freude. Wir haben mit Spaß mit unserem Kater Yurj, aber sollte er sterben, kommt kein Tier mehr ins Haus, dann sind wir ja auch schon zu alt, ich bald 65, Willy 72, Katzen werden ja 18 Jahre alt. Haltet dieOhren steif, Ihr Lieben, laßt Euch trotz allem nicht unterkriegen!. Herzliche Grüße von Anita + Willy mit Andy

English:

> Dear Rose + Friedhelm, thank you for the mail from England; yes the virus will continue to determine all our lives.... Staying at home a lot, we are lucky with the big garden. Can always get out, even if it is a lot of work. Vacations canceled, all stay in Germany, until now many in the Black Forest. Infected with Volker, but all recovered, no one died. We go only with mask in stores, bus + train, but there you have to go through, we read many books, watch TV + play cards. We send this card so you can see the old Monnem water tower in Middlesbrough too. We send a few little things, so you also have a little joy. We have fun with our cat Yurj, but if he should die, no more animal comes into the house, because we are already too old, I soon 65, Willy 72, cats become 18 years old. Keep your ears stiff, dear ones, don't let it get you down in spite of everything! Best regards from Anita + Willy with Andy

*Monnemer Wasserturm* refers to the [Mannheim Water Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mannheim_Water_Tower). *Monnem* is *Mannheim* in the local dialect.

I am sorry for your loss.

Comment: Thank you so much! Apologies, I didn't realise it was a recent postcard as it was mixed in with my Grandads "Ahnentafel" so I presumed it was an old one as the rest of the documents are from the Wars & before. I'll maybe post them too